# Parse This XML to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net, parsing

For some reason this was voted down for being to broad by users who don't know much about xml and objects.  This was definitely not a broad question.  This is XML and was converted into objects using the qualified answer.

I have the following XML and I am not sure how to parse it into an object.  I am not familiar with this type of xml.  What is my first step?  I would like to parse it into an object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<DATA_PROVIDERS UID="Providers|REP" FORCE_REFRESH="FALSE" DATA_PROVIDER="" FORMATTED="FALSE" REFRESH="TRUE">
<DATA_PROVIDER NAME="Prov" SOURCE="Provider" DATE="11/18/2014" DURATION="9s" REFRESH="TRUE" CUBE="1">
  <COLUMN INDEX="0" ID="119" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Prov ID</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="1" ID="118" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Prov Name</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="2" ID="113" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Address Info</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="3" ID="110" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Enroll Status Code</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="4" ID="119" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Phone</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="5" ID="110" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Fax</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="6" ID="109" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Provider Status</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="7" ID="150" TYPE="Date" FORMAT="m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss am/pm">Provider Start Date</COLUMN> 
<ROW>
  <CELL INDEX="0">004042111</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="1">CONTOSO West INC</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="2">1234 Random Rd. SOMECITY, ZZ 12345 9876</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="3">F</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="4">5555551234123</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="5">5555551234</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="6">F - Agency Action</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="7">5/31/2011 12:00:00 AM</CELL> 
  </ROW>
<ROW>
  <CELL INDEX="0">004011117</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="1">CONTOSO North INC</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="2">4321 Random Rd. SOMECITY, ZZ 12345 9876</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="3">F</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="4">5555551234123</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="5">5555551234</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="6">F - Agency Action</CELL> 
  <CELL INDEX="7">5/31/2011 12:00:00 AM</CELL> 
  </ROW>
 </DATA_PROVIDER>
</DATA_PROVIDERS>
```

Comment: `I am not familiar with this type of xml` There is nothing special in this xml. You can use any document about xml parsing. (BTW: if your question is not *write it for me*, post what you have done so far)

Comment: Depends on what the `object` is and how you want to parse it in

Comment: if this is valid XML why not use DataTable.LoadFromXML() along with a DataSetor something and loop thru the dataset that way..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE: not all XML maps to a DataSet

Comment: I am aware of that John that's why I qualified it with `if this is valid XML` but I do agree

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I mean not all valid XML maps to a DataSet.

Comment: understandable I gotcha now.. you're correct on that as well..

Comment: This was not to be mapped to a dataset it was to be mapped to an class object.  Down voters explain why you down voted this question it was a valid question and it received a valid answer.  I was able to use this answer to map this xml to an object.  With it being closed other people aren't as able to receive the good information provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2012 (or greater) and you're targeting .NET 4.5 (or greater) then Visual Studio can create a class for you that matches the XML:

- Copy the XML to your clipboard
- From within Visual Studio: Edit --> Paste Special --> Paste XML As Classes

Then you'll need to serialize the data from XML to your newly created class to create a new object:

```
var myObject = LoadFromXmlString<DATA_PROVIDERS>(xmlData);

public static T LoadFromXmlString<T>(string xml)
{
  T retval = default(T);
  try
  {
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(xml));
    retval = (T)s.Deserialize(ms);
    ms.Close(); 
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ex.Data.Add("Xml String", xml);
    throw new Exception("Error loading from XML string.  See data.", ex);
  }
  return retval;

}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do this- that's cool.

Comment: Which version of VS is this in, and which edition?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I think 2012 (maybe even 2010) onward all editions.  Edit: N/A to 2010

Comment: Just tried it in VS2013 Ultimate. It had "Paste JSON as classes", but not "Paste XML as classes"

Comment: @JohnSaunders Ahh, looks like your project must be targeting .NET 4.5.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you this worked to fill the object and I learned some new stuff.  I didn't know you could do that in VS2012 that's a good feature.