# deserialize an XML object returned from SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, deserialization

I need to deserialize an XML object that 'should' be returned from a SQL query.

I had this working in JSON, but cannot use JSON so I am moving over to XML. The JsonConvert functionality gets my result in one line.. but I am not really sure how to handle what SQL gives me.

When writing to the server the Table is getting an Xdocument type, into a xml datatype cell.

```
        if (do_sql_read)
        {
            List<string> usernames = new List<string>();
            List<int> ids = new List<int>();
            string sql_load;

            Player player_after_load = new Player();

            //multiple
            string select_string = @"SELECT * FROM [Table]";

            using (SqlConnection sql_connection_a = new SqlConnection( GetConnectionString() ) )
            {
                sql_connection_a.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(select_string, sql_connection_a))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);

                    // XML VERSION
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int iii = reader.GetInt32(0);    // unique id int
                        string name = reader.GetString(1);  // Name string
                        sql_load = reader.GetString(2);
                        usernames.Add(name);
                        ids.Add(iii);

                        XmlSerializer XML_serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(Player));


                        // <<<<< THIS PART ??? >>>
                        player_after_load = (Player)XML_serializer.Deserialize (sql_load);

                        Console.WriteLine("SQLPlayer:  " + iii + " " + player_after_load.name + " " + player_after_load.health + " " + player_after_load.mana);
                    }


                    /* JSON VERSION WORKS
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int iii = reader.GetInt32(0);    // unique id int
                        string name = reader.GetString(1);  // Name string
                        sql_load = reader.GetString(2);
                        usernames.Add(name);
                        ids.Add(iii);

                        player_after_load = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(sql_load);
                        Console.WriteLine("SQLPlayer:  " + iii + " " + player_after_load.name + " " + player_after_load.health + " " + player_after_load.mana);
                    }
                    */
                }
            }

        } // end do_sql_string
```

Comment: See if my answer for another question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003701/parse-this-xml-to-object/27003826#27003826

Comment: It looks like you're trying to deserialize JSON string with XmlSerializer. I think that won't work (since your JsonConvert call does work, I assume that sql_load - field index 2 - contains JSON data, not XML).

Comment: I have converted everything to XML

Comment: Do you get any error when deserializing?

Comment: the line:         

player_after_load = (Player)XML_serializer.Deserialize (sql_load);    

is the only error. "Best overloaded method match... has invalid arguments. I know this is because I am not deserializing properly. 
I dont really know what is being returned into sql_load . it WAS json string, now its XMLdocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only adding this answer because you said you cannot use System.IO.  If you can use System.IO please refer to DatVM's answer.  Here is a sample of what you could do.  I simplified this so that it includes a class to deserialize to, and it can be run in any console app.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Player
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "<Player><Name>Bobby</Name></Player>";
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var XML_serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Player));
        doc.LoadXml(str);
        Player player_after_load;
        using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(doc))
        {
            player_after_load = (Player)XML_serializer.Deserialize(nodeReader);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(player_after_load.Name);

    }
}
```

Console Results

```
Bobby
```

Comment: This was the most direct answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[XMLSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)'s `Deserialize` method does not have any overload that take a string. You can use `Stream` (using [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx)) instead:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml))) {
    player_after_load = (Player)XML_serializer.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

P.s: your variable names are terrible. You should see a C# Coding Convention.

Comment: I'd throw a using statement around that MemoryStream.

Comment: Yes, these names are certainly not good. But, in response to your (very helpful) response... what if memorystream was unavailable (I cannot use System.IO)

Comment: @MichaelMeritt can you use an XmlReader?  You could do the same thing with that.

Comment: @MichaelMeritt I afraid it is not possible, since every overload of XmlSerializer use `System.IO` namespace. Maybe your alternative now is `BinaryFormatter` as in redmanmale's answer

Comment: @thinklarge `XmlReader` cannot be initialized using constructor, and its `Create` static methods use `System.IO` too (the `string` overload is for URI)

Comment: OK this is kind of crazy, but you can use XmlDocument.LoadXml to load your string into that document.  THEN you use XmlNodeReader to read that XmlDocument.  No System.IO.

Comment: @DatVM yup yup.  I meant to suggest XmlNodeReader.  Which inherits from XmlReader.  I've used that on XmlDocuments before.

Answer (score 0):

But before that you need to create class with `[Serializable]` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject
{
     public int n1;
     public int n2;
     public String str;
 }
```

Then use standart deserializer:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MyObject obj = (MyObject) formatter.Deserialize(your_xml_object);
```