# Deserialize JSON array Object to c# class type conversion

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-2.1

I get JSON data from `[HttpPost]` in below format. I want to de-serialize to two C# Models.

```
data {{ 
  "invoiceNumber": "55",
  "invoiceDate": "2018-10-25T13:16:37.843Z",
  "invoiceValue": 55,
  "remarks": null,'
  "items": [
    {
      "gRNNo": "0000000",
      "itemCode": 1,
      "itemDesc": "Lux",
      "qty": "2",      
    },
    {
      "gRNNo": "0000000",
      "itemCode": 2,
      "itemDesc": "Rexona",
      "qty": "1"      
    }
  ]
}}
```

I am able to get Header data but items array.

```
PurHeader purHeader = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PurHeader>(data.ToString()); //Working for Header
```

but failed in getting array data. I tried following.

```
    List<PurDetail> purDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PurDetail>>(data["items"].ToString());
var purDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PurDetail[]>(data["items"].ToString());
```

My Classes - I use them in Code First. And `data` json comes from `Angular 7 ReactiveForms`

```
public class PurHeader
    {        
        public string GRNNo { get; set; }        
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public decimal InvoiceValue { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PurDetail> PurDetail { get; set; }
    }

public class PurDetail
    {
        public string GRNNo { get; set; }
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
        public decimal Qty { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GRNNo")]
        public PurHeader PurHeader { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the C# classes? I have no idea what are `PurHeader` and `PurDetails`...

Comment: What type is your ```data``` object?

Comment: You wrote "And data json comes from Angular 7 ReactiveForms" But what type of data is in your ASP.NET code? When it comes to controller.

Comment: Receive as [FromBody] JObject data. Need to send to PurHeader and array of PurDetail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is malformed, I hope that's just a typo in your question.  However, you should be able to parse the whole set with these classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
  public string invoiceNumber { get; set; }
  public DateTime invoiceDate { get; set; }
  public int invoiceValue { get; set; }
  public object remarks { get; set; }
  public Item[] items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
  public string gRNNo { get; set; }
  public int itemCode { get; set; }
  public string itemDesc { get; set; }
  public string qty { get; set; }
}

Rootobject purHeader = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data.ToString());
```

Also see my answer here on how to easily derive classes from XML (same applies to JSON): [Parse This XML to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003701/parse-this-xml-to-object/27003826#27003826)

Comment: It gives me null values.

Comment: I'm able to parse it (after fixing the supplied JSON).  Can you fix your JSON above to the actual data you're using?  As I mention above, they JSON you show is malformed.

Comment: In your answer, u mentioned json is malformed but data comes from Angular 7 ReactiveForms. I dont do any manupulation in that.

Comment: What's with the apostrophe at the end of this section: `"remarks": null,'`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `data` doesn't have two `{{` your code should work.
But you could do it without casting to **string**, just:

```
var purHeader = data.ToObject<PurHeader>();
var purDetails = data["items"].ToObject<PurDetail[]>();
```